# Overlay a play icon on top of thumbnail with css

Tags: html, css, icons, overlay, thumbnails

I trying to overlay a play icon on top of thumbnail with css, but not successful.

```
<ul class="thumb-grid">
        <li class="play-icon"><img src="image.url"/></li>
</ul>
```

You can see the icon when hovering but can't get the icon to go on top of the thumbnail.
Does anyone know how?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmdj2yq/11/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and change the `position` style.

To preserve your hovering effect you can attach the `:hover` selector to the list item and target the `img` inside:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 750px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    background-color: #eee;
}
p {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
.play-icon:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/video-controls/32/play-20.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.thumb-grid {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3em 0 3em 0;
    background-color:;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.thumb-grid:after {
    content:'';
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.thumb-grid li {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 16%;
    margin: 0 5% 5% 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 16%;
}
.thumb-grid li:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.thumb-grid img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.thumb-grid li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>Een dynamische quiz in teams, die wordt geleid door een enthousiaste en bekwame quizmaster. Doormiddel van beeld en geluid wordt een breed scala aan vragen voorgelegd. Het raden van tunes, videofragmenten, teksten, foto’s met de hand op de quiz-knop of na teamberaad.</p>
    <ul class="thumb-grid">
        <li class="play-icon"><img src="http://images.kaneva.com/filestore9/5112880/6412551/squareUyellowUsmileyUface_ad.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://images.kaneva.com/filestore9/5112880/6412551/squareUyellowUsmileyUface_ad.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://images.kaneva.com/filestore9/5112880/6412551/squareUyellowUsmileyUface_ad.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://images.kaneva.com/filestore9/5112880/6412551/squareUyellowUsmileyUface_ad.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://images.kaneva.com/filestore9/5112880/6412551/squareUyellowUsmileyUface_ad.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks of course :after element, but the hover effect disappears does it need a separate hover code :after:hover etc. ?

Comment: Thanks mate! Oh of course li:hover sorry that was simple my head is full with code at the moment. Great stuff!