# Overlay icon with css without losing click events/links

Tags: css, overlay

I was looking for a way to implement a simple css overlay to show a zoom icon over an image.
I found the "almost" correct answer here: [Overlay a play icon on top of thumbnail with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753062/overlay-a-play-icon-on-top-of-thumbnail-with-css)

Thing is that it "strips out" the link in the element. I have a link to a larger picture with prettyphoto, and the icon is not linking. It has no click events whatsoever.

Is there a way to keep the links below the overlay?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play icon has a really high `z-index` and is covering the link. Try adding the `play-icon` class to the `<a>` instead of the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="play-icon" href="..."><img src="..." alt="..." /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You would likely need to adjust some of the styles from your referenced solution as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly, just adding the class to the <a> tag :)